# Как вызвать Windows Form из консольного приложения?

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль

Имеется проект обычного консольного приложения. Программа предназначена для работы с графами. В программе имеется двумерный массив (матрица смежности графа).

Так как визуализировать (нарисовать) граф в консоли — это не очень красиво, причём довольно хлопотно, возникает вопрос:

Как вызвать форму Windows Forms, которая бы отображала нарисованный граф? Как её подключить, чтобы её код содержался в отдельном файле и чтобы она показываласьпри вызове из консоли?

К слову, на данный момент есть идея с сохранением массива в текстовый файл из консольного приложения, загрузкой его в форме и построением графа в соответствии с ним.

Comment: а зачем вам вообще консольное приложение и тем более вызывать из него что-то?  Почему не делать все сразу в WinForms?

Comment: @dreamchild, просто уже есть программа, которая реализует всё нужное, кроме рисовки. При этом нет особо времени продумывать интерфейс в формах, тем более при моём не очень большом опыте.

Comment: @AlexanderArtamonov: Тогда, боюсь, у вас будут проблемы. Если у вас приложение командной строки, то оно проводит все вычисления в главном потоке, не обращая внимания на нужды отрисовки. Приделать UI «сбоку», в последний момент не получится. Думаю, мы ещё увидим вопросы от вас.

Comment: @VladD, да нет, вроде бы всё получается.

Comment: @AlexanderArtamonov: Хорошо, если так. Обычно перестройка линейного кода на событийно-ориентированную архитектуру довольно болезненна.

Comment: VladD, я думаю, автор вопроса сначала готовит данные - а потом уже только показывает. Это совершенно нормальный сценарий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- В консольный проект добавляем Reference на сборку System.Windows.Forms
- делаем using System.Windows.Forms;
- добавляем в консольный проект форму через Add ... Windows Forms
- Вызываем форму